# kivy. Popup can have only one widget as content

Tags: python, kivy

I'm sure that the above error is caused by double popups are loaded.
But I can't detect the bug in my codes.
I think that ImageWidget is loaded only one time.
And then NyPopUp isn't loaded until button1 is clicked.
Here are my scripts.
How to fix it?

test.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase, DEFAULT_FONT
from kivy.resources import resource_add_path
from random import randint
from kivy.lang import Builder

resource_add_path("./image")

Builder.load_file('cat.kv')


class ImageWidget(Widget):
    source = StringProperty("./image/0.jpg")
    
    def buttonStared(self):
        self.source="./image/0.jpg"

    def buttonRandom(self):
        self.source = f"{randint(0,2)}.jpg"

class MyTestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ImageWidget()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyTestApp().run()
```

cat.kv

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<MyPopup@Popup>:
    auto_dismiss:False
    orientation: "vertical"
    size_hint: 0.5, 0.5
    title:"Popup "
    Label:
        text: "reset OK？"
        center: root.center
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "OK"
        Button:
            text: "NO"

<ImageWidget>:
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.size
        Image:
            source: root.source
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                id: button1
                text : "Go back to first cat Image"
                on_press: Factory.MyPopup().open()

            Button:
                id: button2
                text: "Rondom Image"
                on_press : root.buttonRandom()
```

Comment: Try setting the [`content`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.popup.html#examples) of popup.

Comment: Your `kv` file has two children specified for `MyPopup`, a `Label` and a `BoxLayout`. There can only be one.

Answer (score 0):

Your Popup() actually has **TWO child widgets.**

```
<MyPopup@Popup>:
    auto_dismiss:False
    orientation: "vertical"
    size_hint: 0.5, 0.5
    title:"Popup "
    Label:
        text: "reset OK？"
        center: root.center
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "OK"
        Button:
            text: "NO"
```

**BoxLayout** and **Label**

if you want to keep both, add a box layout first right after popup widget, then add multiple widgets under that box layout.

```
<MyPopup@Popup>:
    auto_dismiss:False
    orientation: "vertical"
    size_hint: 0.5, 0.5
    title:"Popup "
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "orientation_here"
        Label:
            text: "reset OK？"
            center: root.center
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: "OK"
            Button:
                text: "NO"
```